# Expanding a DL list on page visit

Tags: css, html

I have a page with a lot of content in a dl that is expandable/collapsible through JQuery

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a link on another page that would take the user to a specific part inside the dl.

I've tried to use regular page anchors but they don't expand the list.

```
<dl class="faq">
    <dt style="text-indent:20px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding-top: 0px; background: none;"><u>TITLE</u></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>
        content
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

css:

```
.faq { clear: both; padding-top: 5px; }
.faq dt { line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: -1px; padding: 5px 0; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea; background: url(img/common/icon-plus2.gif) no-repeat right 12px;  text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; } 
.faq dt:hover, .faq dt.hover { cursor: pointer; color: #073873; }
.faq dt.open { background-image: url(img/common/icon-minus2.gif); }
.faq dd { display: none; padding: 5px 0; }
.faqcontrols { float: right; }
.faqcontrols a { font-weight: bold; }
.faqcontrols span { font-size: 125%; vertical-align: bottom; }
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".faq dt").click(function() { $(this).next().slideToggle("fast"); $(this).toggleClass("open"); });
   $(".faqexpand").click(function() { $(this).parent().next().children("dd").slideDown("fast"); return false; });
   $(".faqcollapse").click(function() { $(this).parent().next().children("dd").slideUp("fast"); return false; });
```

Comment: What JavaScript code or plugin are you using to make the `dl` expandible? You probably have to call it again to expand the `dl` as necessary.

Comment: Just added the JQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

Put an anchor link wherever you want the page to go to.

E.g.

```
<dl class="faq">
    <dt style="text-indent:20px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding-top: 0px; background: none;"><u>TITLE</u></dt>
    <dd>
        <a name="anchorHere"></a>
        <p>
        content
        </p>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Then in the link to that would be:

```
<a href="yourpage.html#anchorHere">Click here</a>
```

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work. Can you provide a live link to the issue?

Comment: The dl list is expandable/collapsible  with jquery. (collapsed by default) If it were a regular dl list the anchor would work.

Comment: Oh I see. You didn't post any jQuery with your original code!

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just added it now.